# Find direction of given x,y,z cordinates

Tags: c++, opencv

i'm new to opencv & it's developing. I have x,y,z coordinates ( 0.00949334694383068, -0.3999829847985352, 0.8449078780010854) by using the given coordinates how could i find the direction.

```
for an example 
input one : x,y,z =  0.00949334694383068, -0.3999829847985352, 0.8449078780010854
input two : x,y,z =   0.01603883281370779, 0.6066595296580494, 0.5342810849038371
```

At the finally i want to compare input_one direction and input_two direction. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called vector math.

"Coordinates" are a special kind of vector, relative to some origin (in your case `x=0,y=0,z=0`). For that reason, the difference `x1-x2, y1-y2, z1-z2` is a vector *from* point 2 *to* point 1. The inverse `x2-x1, y2-y1, z2-z1` is a vector *from* point 1 *to* point 2.

The *direction* of a vector is usually defined by ignoring its length, or alternatively by setting its length to one. So we need to first define the length, which is `L = √(x*x + y*y + z*z)`. We can define the vector `x/L, y/L, z/L` which points in the same direction as `x,y,z` but with length one.

Finally, to compare two directions we can calculate the *inner product* of those two directions: `x1/L1 * x2/L2 + y1/L1 * y2/L2 + z1/L1 * z2/L2`. If that's one, they point in the same direction. If it's 0, they're orthogonal. If it's -1, they point in opposite directions.

As you can see, the vector 0,0,0 has length 0 and no direction. That can complicate things a bit.

In OpenCV: [class Vec](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d6/dcf/classcv_1_1Vec.html). The length function is called `norm(v)` and the inner product is called `v1.mul(v2)`

Comment: MSalters this is my another idea if i take x & y and compute sin value i think i can take the direction. But for that i dont have good idea for implementation level. if you could explain it also it will be too helpful.

Comment: this is my another idea if i take x & y and compute sin value i think i can take the direction. But for that i dont have good idea for implementation level. if you could explain it also it will be too helpful

Comment: @RahulaCol: No, `sin(x/y)` wouldn't give a meaningful result.You can use `atan2(y,x)`.

Comment: thank you so much. i will see atan2(y,x) function in opencv.

Comment: @RahulaCol: It's in `<cmath>`, aka `std::atan2`, not in OpenCV.

Comment: thank you you're correct. i just implemented it and its working.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called calculating the azimuth. If you're interested in doing this for navigational or geographic purposes and need a thorough understanding of this, you can start here:

http://mobile.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/algorithms/article.php/c5115/Geographic-Distance-and-Azimuth-Calculations.htm

Otherwise you could look for a library for calculating the azimuth bases on 3d co-ordinates